# web extraction software and spiders with GUI

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for an email and data extraction programme to build a mailing list for particular industries, I am looking for one with a simple GUI but has extensive capabilities and easy to use on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like HTTrack to create a local static mirror of the site first. Then `cd` into the local mirror and `grep` for email addresses:

```
grep -srhwoIiE "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}" . \
| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' \
| sort -u
```

There are probably better regexes for emails (it's notoriously difficult because the email RFC is so loose) but that should get you going.

Comment: That's great oli, is there anyway of getting more fields than just the email addresses? are there any programmes which can do it directly off the sites?